# How can I get parameters from previous conversation on dialogflow?

Tags: node.js, parameters, dialogflow-es

I want to get parameters from previous conversation.
How can I store parameters during continued conversation?
I have to send the previous parameters to the webhook.
I will use the parameters to search data from the database
I thought about using outputContexts in the dialogflow request.body.
but when I tried to use request.body.outputContexts.parameters, it did not work.

```html
exports.dialogflowFirebaseFulfillment = functions.https.onRequest(
  (request, response) => {
    const agent = new WebhookClient({ request, response });

    console.log(
      'Dialogflow Request headers: ' + JSON.stringify(request.headers)
    );

    //this works. 
    console.log('Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body));

    //this does not work. (request.body.outputContexts) even outputContexts is in request.body.
    console.log(JSON.stringify(request.body.outputContexts));
```

[Dialogflow Request body: ' + JSON.stringify(request.body)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dXDb9.png)

[request.body.outputContexts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vf4Cc.png)

Comment: Please show the code that you have tried, and explain what about it doesn't work.

Comment: @Aurast I add code now

Comment: Have you followed this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/es/docs/fulfillment-webhook) to create a webhook for your Agent?

Comment: @user16509707 How you are maintaining the uniqueness for the 2 conversations. Let take an example I'm a user and I did one conversation, after completing the one conversation I again start the conversation( based on your explanation, you need the all the parameters captured in the past conversation right?) then how you are managing that the same user has did both the conversations.

Comment: OH..! I found a problem. I can use that. just I misread the object structure.

Comment: @user16509707 could you post the answer? So it further contribute to the community.